# Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject, FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: java, android-asynctask

I am trying to get some user inputs. More specifically, I want to get someone to enter a value as speed and when I click calculate then my `if ... else if` structures will calculate the resulting amount to pay as fine and display it.

Then when I click save then these input data including resulting fine should be uploaded to my SAL database.

Unfortunately when I click *save* *i* get a long list of errors... It'd be great if someone could point out what I am doing wrong so that I could learn from my mistakes. This is my first time doing this so I get a little lost here and there.

Find my Java code below:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;
import android.app.Dialog;
import java.text.*;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.finecalc.library.JSONParser;
import com.finecalc.ltafinecalculator.FineCalc.CreateNewFine;

public class FineCalc extends Activity {
    private EditText speed;
    private TextView Fine;
    Button btnSelectDate,btnSelectTime;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID=1;
    public  int year,month,day,hour,minute;
    private final int mYear, mMonth, mDay,mHour,mMinute;
    // Button btnRegisterfine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savefine);

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputDriver;
    EditText inputLicence;
    EditText inputOfficer;
    EditText inputSpeed;
    EditText FineAppl;
    EditText inputCategory;
    TextView registerFine;

    // url to create new fine
    private static String url_create_fine = "http://192.168.43.183/androidltafj_api/create_fine.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    public FineCalc()
    {
        // Assign current Date and Time Values to Variables
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        this.mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        this.mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        this.mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        this.mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.speed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        this.Fine = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        this.btnSelectDate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectDate);
        this.btnSelectTime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectTime);
        this.inputDriver = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        this.inputLicence = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        this.inputOfficer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        this.inputSpeed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        this.FineAppl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        this.inputCategory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        this.registerFine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fineregistered);


        // Create button
        final Button btnRegisterfine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savefine);



        // Set ClickListener on btnSelectDate
        this.btnSelectDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(final View v) {
                // Show the DatePickerDialog
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        // Set ClickListener on btnSelectTime
        this.btnSelectTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(final View v) {
                // Show the TimePickerDialog
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });


        // button click event
        btnRegisterfine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewFine().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewFine extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            FineCalc.this.pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FineCalc.this);
            FineCalc.this.pDialog.setMessage("Registering Fine..");
            FineCalc.this.pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            FineCalc.this.pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            FineCalc.this.pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {
            final String driver = FineCalc.this.inputDriver.getText().toString();
            final String licencenum = FineCalc.this.inputLicence.getText().toString();
            final String officer = FineCalc.this.inputOfficer.getText().toString();
            final String speed = FineCalc.this.inputSpeed.getText().toString();
            final String fine= FineCalc.this.FineAppl.getText().toString();
            final String category = FineCalc.this.inputCategory.getText().toString();


            // Building Parameters
            final List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driver", driver));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("licencenum", licencenum));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("officer", officer));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("speed", speed));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fine", fine));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", category));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            final JSONObject json = FineCalc.this.jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_fine, "POST", params);

            // check log cat from response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                final int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    final Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserLogin.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //registerFine.setText("Error occured in registration");

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(final String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            FineCalc.this.pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    public void ShowFine(final View clickedButton) {
        final double SpeedKMh = (Integer.parseInt(this.speed.getText().toString()));
        final TextView Result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText6);

        if ((SpeedKMh>=80) && (SpeedKMh<=99)){
            final double TotalFine = 50;
            this.Fine.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(TotalFine));
            Result.setText("Speeding");
        }

        else if ((SpeedKMh>=56) && (SpeedKMh<=79)) {
            final double TotalFine = 25;
            this.Fine.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(TotalFine));
            Result.setText("Medium Speed");
        }

        else if ((SpeedKMh>=40) && (SpeedKMh<=55)) {
            final double TotalFine = 0;
            this.Fine.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(TotalFine));
            Result.setText("Slow");
        }

        else if (SpeedKMh<=39) {
            final double TotalFine = 0;
            this.Fine.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(TotalFine));
            Result.setText("Very Slow");
        }

        else if (SpeedKMh>=100) {
            final double TotalFine = 100;
            this.Fine.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(TotalFine));
            Result.setText("Over Speeding");
        }
    }

    // Register  DatePickerDialog listener
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {


        // the callback received when the user "sets" the Date in the DatePickerDialog

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yearSelected, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            year = yearSelected;
            month = monthOfYear+1;
            day = dayOfMonth;
            // Set the Selected Date in Select date Button
            btnSelectDate.setText("Date selected: "+day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
        }
    };

    // Register  TimePickerDialog listener

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        // the callback received when the user "sets" the TimePickerDialog in the dialog

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int min) {
            hour = hourOfDay;
            minute = min;
            // Set the Selected Date in Select date Button
            btnSelectTime.setText("Time selected: "+hour+":"+minute);
        }
    };


    // Method automatically gets Called when you call showDialog()  method

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                // create a new DatePickerDialog with values you want to show
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, this.mDateSetListener, this.mYear, this.mMonth, this.mDay);
                // create a new TimePickerDialog with values you want to show
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, this.mTimeSetListener, this.mHour, this.mMinute, false);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

### and my long error list

```
08-03 18:25:50.288: E/JSON Parser(1190): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): Process: com.finecalc.ltafinecalculator, PID: 1190
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at com.finecalc.ltafinecalculator.FineCalc$CreateNewFine.doInBackground(FineCalc.java:187)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at com.finecalc.ltafinecalculator.FineCalc$CreateNewFine.doInBackground(FineCalc.java:1)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-03 18:25:50.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     ... 4 more
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.finecalc.ltafinecalculator.FineCalc has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b3f08e18 V.E..... R......D 0,0-642,345} that was originally added here
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at com.finecalc.ltafinecalculator.FineCalc$CreateNewFine.onPreExecute(FineCalc.java:158)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at com.finecalc.ltafinecalculator.FineCalc$5.onClick(FineCalc.java:139)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-03 18:25:51.628: E/WindowManager(1190):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your logs, your code is pointing `NullPointerException` that's why `JSONObject` is not parsed properly as it cannot parse empty data. So check your code that which part is giving `NullPointerException`

Comment: ok so i have managed to sort out the NullPointerException. Now iam left with one error when it tries to register and that is:
08-03 23:00:46.060: E/JSON Parser(1030): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-03 23:00:48.470: E/JSON Parser(1030): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Check the data that you are trying to parse by using `Logcat` or any other method to check whether the data you are trying to parse is parsable or not.